# Understading Solr nested queries

Tags: solr, subquery

I'm trying to understand solr nested queries but I'm having a problem undestading the syntax.

I have the following two indexed documents (among others):

```
<doc>
    <str name="city">Guarulhos</str>
    <str name="name">Fulano Silva</str>
</doc>

<doc>
    <str name="city">Fortaleza</str>
    <str name="name">Fulano Cardoso Silva</str>
</doc>
```

If I query for `q="Fulano Silva"~2&defType=edismax&qf=name&fl=score` I have:

```
<doc>
    <float name="score">28.038431</float>
    <str name="city">Guarulhos</str>
    <str name="name">Fulano Silva</str>
</doc>

<doc>
    <float name="score">19.826164</float>
    <str name="city">Fortaleza</str>
    <str name="name">Fulano Cardoso Silva</str>
</doc>
```

So I thought that if I queried for:

```
q="Fulano Silva"~2 AND __query__="{!edismax qf=city}fortaleza" &defType=edismax&qf=name&fl=score
```

I'd give a bit more score for the second document, but actually I get an empty result set with numFound=0.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: add debugQuery=true to your query parameters and see extended info. BTW, space before &defType looks suspicious.

Comment: What is the `city` type? Is it a solr.StrField or solr.TextField?

Answer (score 1):

Need to remove the "=" and replace it with ":" to use the nested query syntax:

q="Fulano Silva"~2 AND **_query_:**"{!edismax qf=city}fortaleza" &defType=edismax&qf=name&fl=score

*Use **_query_:** instead of **_query_=**

Hope this works...

Comment: hummm... nope. No luck. Tried `__query__:xxx`, `_query_:xxx`, `__query__=xxx` and `_query_=xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: When you say** `q=`, **are you specifying the query in a URL, or is the text after the** `q=` **being put in an application or the Solr dashboard?** If we're talking about a URL, you may need to use [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_encoding) to get it to work. I mentioned that below, but since I haven't heard from you, I thought I'd reiterate.

Why don't you do `q=name:"Fulano Silva" AND city:"fortaleza"`?

Another possibility: `q=_query_:"{!edismax qf='name'}Fulano Silva" AND city:"fortaleza"`

If you're set on a nested query, `select?defType=edismax&q="Fulano Silva" AND _query_:"{!edismax qf='city' v='fortaleza'}"` should work, but the results and the way it matches will depend on what analyzers you are using to query and index `name` and `city`. Also, if these queries are in your query string, make sure you are 
[encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_encoding) them properly.

In order to help you any more, I need to know what you're trying to accomplish with your query. Then perhaps we can be sure you have the right indexing set up, that edismax is the right query handler, etc.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the previous comments, the asker has mispelled `_query_` as `__query__` (note the double underscore in the second, mispelled, version); Solr expects `_query_` to be spelled with only one underscore (`_`) before and one after the word query, not two.