# Solr TF vs All Terms match

Tags: solr, lucene

I have observed that Solr/Lucene gives too much weightage to matching all the query terms over tf of a particular query term.
e.g.
Say our query is : text: ("red" "jacket" "red jacket")
Document A ->  contains "jacket" 40 times
Document B -> contains "red jacket" 1 time (and because of this "red" 1 time and "jacket" 1 time as well)

Document B is getting much higher score as its containing all the three terms of the query but just once whereas Document A is getting very low score even though it contains one term large number of times.

Can I create a query in such a manner that if Lucene finds a match for "red jacket" it does not consider it as match for "red" and "jacket" individually ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a [DisjunctionMaxQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/DisjunctionMaxQuery.html).  In raw Lucene, this would look something like:

```
Query dismax = new DisjunctionMaxQuery(0);
dismax.add(parser.parse("red"));
dismax.add(parser.parse("junction"));
dismax.add(parser.parse("red jacket"));
```

The dismax query will score using the maximum score among it's subqueries, rather than the product of the scores of it's subqueries.

Using Solr, the [dismax](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) and [edismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax) query parsers are the way to go for this, as well as many other handy features.  Something like:

```
select/?q=red+jacket+"red jacket"&defType=dismax
```

Comment: But if I have another term which I do want to add in the score. e.g. q = red+jacket+"red jacket"+car ...  Now in this query I would like score to be = maxof(red,jacket,"red jacket") + maxof(car)..   Is this something which is possible ?

Comment: so basically, it boils down to same basic question, is there a way in which I can make solr consider a term in document only once, i.e. say if there is a match for "red jacket" in a document, solr matches it and then removes it for further considerations so that it does not matches other query terms like "red" or "jacket" ?

Comment: Sounds like a semantic fine semantic distinction, when dismax queries serve the same functional purpose.  But, if you care about the implementation details, then I'm reasonably confident saying no, there is nothing that does precisely that.  Dismax is the standard way to accomplish this.  If you need to know about nested queries, you might take a look at: [Understanding Solr nested queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389226/understading-solr-nested-queries).

Answer (score 1):

Tf-idf is what search engines normally do but not what you always want. It is not what you want if you want to ignore repeated key words.

Tf-idf is calculated as the product of to factors: tf x idf. tf (term frequency) is how frequent a word is in a text. idf (inverse document frequency) means how unique a word is among all documents that you have in a search engine.

Consider a text containing 100 words wherein the word cat appears 3 times. The term frequency (i.e., tf) for cat is then (3 / 100) = 0.03. Now, assume we have 10 million documents and the word cat appears in one thousand of these. Then, the inverse document frequency (i.e., idf) is calculated as log(10,000,000 / 1,000) = 4. Thus, the Tf-idf weight is the product of these quantities: 0.03 * 4 = 0.12. See [original source](http://www.tfidf.com/) of example.

The best way to ignore tf-idf is probably the Solr exists function, which is accessible through the bf relevance boost parameter. For example:

*bf=if(exists(query(location:A)),5,if(exists(query(location:B)),3,0))*

See [original source](http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/12atp9e4cv/edismax-bq-ignore-tf-idf) and context of second example.