# In solr,how to design the fields to store messages on this condition?

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to index book informations in a solr core.As we know,one book often has more than one author,and each author has a property of age.Later,I should perform queries like this:query the books whose author's age is under 35.
On this Condition ,how should I design the fields of book informations and how should I compose the query to search?

Answer (score 0):

this might guide you in writing SOLR queries.    https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

I'm not adept in writing SOLR queries but I hope this might steer you to the right direction.

If books contain multiple authors, then perform a wildcard search on authors:

> authors:[*0 to 35 *]

I'm not a master in writing nested queries, but this might help: 
[Understading Solr nested queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389226/understading-solr-nested-queries)